# Access ID of conn.query result

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

After executing a sql query, I want to access the id (primary key) of the returned event so that I can use it in another sql. I tried to access it by using result.insertId, but that seems to be null for the returned event object. I even console logged result.insertId but that just came out "Undefined"

```
var sql = "SELECT  * FROM events WHERE events.start_time > '" + dateSql +
        "' ORDER BY events.start_time ASC LIMIT 1;"
    con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(result.insertId)
        var sql = 'SELECT admins.first_name FROM events INNER JOIN admins_has_events ' +
            'ON events.id = admins_has_events.events_id INNER JOIN admins ON ' +
            "admins_has_events.admins_id = admins.id WHERE events.id = '" + result.insertId + "';"
        con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
result[0].id;  // if the ID column name is id
```

- The `insertId` is for getting the auto increment ID after you INSERT. It won't work with SELECT
- When you select, `result` will be array of row. In your case, there is either zero or one row since you LIMIT 1. So you can check weather the ID exists by doing `if (result.length === 0) { // not found, do something else }`